# PostgreSQL - 2 SELECT Statements from 2 different tables into 2 Columns?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I asked a similar question yesterday but still having a slight problem on output. Unions only always combines it into one column and there is no relation to do a join. Here is what I want. I don't want to combine.

```
SELECT prd_id FROM products WHERE title LIKE %$var%;

AND

SELECT lst_id FROM lists WHERE title LIKE %$var%;
```

I want both of these in one query and output the results it finds into 2 columns IF there is a result for either one. I also would like to use a LIMIT at the end too.

So for example if both tables have an item that matches the title then it will return something like. Note the values will be whatever it matched in each table. The point is just to be in 2 columns instead of one like Unions output.

```
+-----------------+  
| prd_id | lst_id |   
+-----------------+   
|  value | value  |   
+-----------------+
```

I get close but just can't it exactly.

To make it clear, the PHP print_r output should be like this. This example is if 2 items are matched in the list table only

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [lst_id] => 100007 ) [1] => Array ( [lst_id] => 100008 ))
```

This example is if 1 item from each table is matched

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [prd_id] => 100006 ) [1] => Array ( [lst_id] => 100008 ))
```

There can be any number of matches from either of the tables.

Comment: Isn't that a simple full outer join on `title`?

Comment: Well, that is an example. It's part of a search query I'm working on and there can be many conditions after the WHERE including matching other fields in each table. I was just trying to use that as example of what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do your queries produce the same number of rows?

Comment: not necessarily, whatever it finds in the tables it will return. There could be 10 row that match in one table and 2 the matched from the other. Just depends on if query finds anything. The problem is I need it to use the specific ID column for each table so I can use PHP to do stuff to it, so they can't be in the same column because it will then show the same key for all values that are returned.

Comment: So if there are 10 rows returned from one table and 2 rows retruned from the other, do you want to see 12 rows or 10 rows returned?

Comment: @Pjack: Is your second example really correct? I would have expected, that one entry would have both `prd_id` and `lst_id` set but your example shows two independent entries where the first one has `prd_id` set and the second one has `lst_id` set. But there is no relation between these entries.

Comment: @Mark, I want to see all 12 rows.

Comment: @AH, yes it's correct, that's what I want to accomplish. If match a prd_id and a lst_id then it will show both in the array when I use the php print_r to show the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to union the results into different column, like so:

```
SELECT prd_id, 0 lst_id FROM products WHERE title LIKE %$var%
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 prd_id, lst_id FROM lists WHERE title LIKE %$var%;
```

Comment: Well, the problem that I get with that is it will show 0 for column it doesn't match. Is it possible for it just not to show up if there is not match. Your answer will give me this   `Array ( [0] => Array ( [prd_id] => 100452 [lst_id] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [prd_id] => 0 [lst_id] => 100008 ) [2] => Array ( [prd_id] => 0 [lst_id] => 100007 ) )` instead can the query be done to give me this instead  `Array ( [0] => Array ( [prd_id] => 100452 ) [1] => Array ( [lst_id] => 100008 ) [2] => Array ( [lst_id] => 100007 ) )`

Comment: @Pjack: I'm not familiar with PHP, so I don't understand what you are asking. Can you format your desired results as query output, instead?

Comment: I did in the first post. Like this                                 `+-----------------+  
| prd_id | lst_id |   
+-----------------+   
| 100452 | 100008 |   
+-----------------+`

Comment: the comments don't really format well. But at the top in the org post, I have the table example with the word value in each row. That's how I want the output, but the values won't say value it will actually have the id # that it returns if a match is found. Otherwise the rows doesn't even show up.

Comment: @Pjack: The actual values are not included in your original question, while this comment only allows for 1 value from each table and appears to contradict your earlier comment where you said "@Mark, I want to see all 12 rows". I suggest you edit your original question to **clearly display** your desired query output, for a sample set of data.

Comment: actually don't worry about. Your answer will work. I just use PHP to ignore the 0 values and it seems to work out. I just like it to be less code so it doesn't process slowly with large results. Hope it doesn't as I have no way to check on large results. Thanks